# How to provide module dependencies for required script in a sibling directory

Tags: node.js, module, require

I am running a node.js script (`foo.js`) that `require`s a helper script that is located in a sibling directory.

`//foo.js:

var magic = require('../util/magic');`

`magic.js` uses a npm module `express`. However, the main directory of the 'program' (holding `package.json` and `node_modules`) is the folder where `foo.js` is located.

```
/program  
  /node_modules  
     /express
     ..
  /foo.js  
  /package.json  
/util  
  /magic.js
```

When running the program, the statement `require('express')` in **magic.js** fails - the module cannot be found.

Is there a way to make node.js load the `express` module from the `program/node_modules` directory?

I would like to avoid any of the following:

- move the node_modules directory to a common parent of `util` and `program`
- add a `node_modules` directory to `util`
- pass in a reference of the required modules to `magic.js`

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could supply a relative path instead the module name, because this is how Node.js is going to check for the modules folder if you don't specify a path:

```
/util/node_modules
/node_modules
```

Since you know where the module already exists, just do this instead:

```
var express = require('../program/node_modules/express');
```

However, you should place any files related to the module within the module itself when developing modules. If you don't, they don't get packaged with the module either when it is published, and you have this inconvenience of not being able to access dependencies specified in the package file.

Comment: I was ignoring the possibility to reference `node_modules` directly out of habit. But I agree that in my specific use-case that is a good and simple solution! Thx!

Comment: The module in `/program` actually never gets published to the npm registry. `/program/package.json` is merely used to load dependencies required to build the program (express is in 'devDependencies'). 
We try to run a dualistic strategy where people can either require modules via npm, or checkout the git repository. It's still in a state of flux though.